# git で コミット(できれば treeish) を `tree` した結果を出力したい

Tags: git

cli 上で git のリポジトリを閲覧していると、たとえばコミットに対して、そのファイル一覧を `tree` した結果がほしくなる場合があります。(これは、 cli 上で普通に `tree` を利用したくなるのと同じ理由で、つまり閲覧性のためです)

素直にチェックアウトして `tree` したとすると、例えば .gitignore しているファイルたちまでその出力に含まれてしまうので、これは自分が今みたいと思っている、「git 管理対象のファイル一覧」ではなくなってしまいます。また、 `git clean -xdf` などを実施してしまうと、今度はプロジェクト用の設定ファイル (例えば `.env` など) まで消えてしまうので、これは避けたいと思っています。

`git ls-tree -r TREEISH` は、近いことができるものの、これはフルパスが表示されてしまい、ディレクトリ構造を把握するにあたっては `tree` 的な出力の方が見やすいので、可能ならば出力をそのようにしたいと考えています。

## 質問

git のコミット(そしてもし可能ならば treeish)に対して、その結果を `tree` したような結果を得るようなツールはありますか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tree` の[1.8.0](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/changes.html)で `--fromfile` オプションが追加されたので `tree` 自体を使えます。

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only TREEISH | tree --fromfile .
```